# Visual Studio multi-project template different name for child project folder and csproj file

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have reviewed a lot of good information regarding Visual Studio Multi-Project templates, including:

- MSDN References for Project Element,  & Project Template Wizards
- Tony Sneed blog - Build a multi-project Visual Studio template

My question is similar to the following question on StackOverflow: 
[Visual Studio Multi-Project Templates rename namespaces and project names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5307176/visual-studio-multi-project-templates-rename-namespaces-and-project-names)

Following is the resulting directory structure after creating a new multi-project template using "MyService" as the name - this is as expected:

```
 - MyService
   - Actor
   - Api
   - Client
   - Interfaces
```

Within the "Actor" Directory, I want the project file to be MyService.Actor.csproj and I end up with Actor.csproj.  Following are excerpts from the Main Template and Actor Template... (BTW I use a Wizard to pass the service name and other files are named as expected)

I expected `TargetFileName=$saferootprojectname$.Actor.csproj` in the child template to result in the name of the project file being `MyService.Actor.csproj` - but it is `actor.csproj` and similarly for all other project files `api.csproj`, `client.csproj` and `interfaces.csproj` (without `MyService` prefix)

**Main Template**

```
<ProjectCollection>
    <SolutionFolder Name="Dependencies">
    </SolutionFolder>   
    <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="Actor">
        Actor\Actor.vstemplate
    </ProjectTemplateLink>
    <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="Api">
        Api\Api.vstemplate
    </ProjectTemplateLink>
    <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="Client">
        Client\Client.vstemplate
    </ProjectTemplateLink>
    <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="Interfaces">
        Interfaces\Interfaces.vstemplate
    </ProjectTemplateLink>
</ProjectCollection>
```

**Child Template**

```
<Project TargetFileName="$saferootprojectname$.Actor.csproj"   File="MyService.Actor.csproj" ReplaceParameters="true">
    <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="App.config">App.config</ProjectItem>
  <Folder Name="PackageRoot" TargetFolderName="PackageRoot">
    <Folder Name="Config" TargetFolderName="Config">
      <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="Settings.xml">Settings.xml</ProjectItem>
    </Folder>
    <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="ServiceManifest.xml">ServiceManifest.xml</ProjectItem>
  </Folder>
  <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="packages.config">packages.config</ProjectItem>
  <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="Ping.cs">Ping.cs</ProjectItem>
  <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="Program.cs">Program.cs</ProjectItem>
  <Folder Name="Properties" TargetFolderName="Properties">
    <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="AssemblyInfo.cs">AssemblyInfo.cs</ProjectItem>
  </Folder>
  <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="ServiceEventSource.cs">ServiceEventSource.cs</ProjectItem>
</Project>
```

Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 is being used.

Comment: 2018 VS2017 Enterprise - using zip based multi-project templates; we have same problem. we want folder names to be small while csproj names to be full like namespaces - this also helps avoid TFS path errors in windows machines